# Substring not being recognized as value

Tags: excel, vba

The macro I'm trying to create would scan a range of cells, extract unique special characters, and place them in an ever growing list of unique special characters (i.e. no special character is listed twice).

I've used code from different sources, but the last issue I'm running into is that when I attempt to set the next empty cell in a column as the special character, Excel produces a 1004: Application-defined or Object-Oriented Error.

```
Sub Main()
Dim sCharOk As String
Dim s As String
Dim r As Range, rc As Range
Dim j As Long

sCharOk = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-() ~!@#%^&*()_+?'."
Set r = Range("A1:A10")

For Each rc In r
    s = rc.Value
    For j = 1 To Len(s)
        If InStr(sCharOk, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B100"), Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then
            rc.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Mid(s, j, 1) = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next rc
End Sub
```

Is there any way to tell Excel to recognize this as a legitimate object or that not the issue?

Comment: which line breaks?

Comment: If there's nothing below B1 then `Range("B1").End(xlDown)` goes down to the last row, and you can't offset one more row from there...  Always safer to work from the bottom using `End(xlUp)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point. However, when I change the code to `End(xlUp)`, no list is created.

Comment: Looks like you're *reading* from the next empty cell, not writing to it though ?  Should that line be the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sCharOk As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range, rc As Range
    Dim j As Long

    sCharOk = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-() ~!@#%^&*()_+?'."
    Set r = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each rc In r
        s = rc.Value
        For j = 1 To Len(s)
            If InStr(sCharOk, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 And _
                  Application.CountIf(Range("B1:B100"), Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then

                rc.Interior.Color = vbYellow

                Cells(rows.count,2).End(xlUp).offset(1,0).value = Mid(s, j, 1)

                Exit For '<<< remove if you want to capture all special chars

            End If
        Next j
    Next rc

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great. One small issue. The code does not appear to be extracting multiple special characters from a cell. For example, if a cell contains the string "sd[]", it only extracts the first bracket. I have no idea how I would even approach the issue.

Comment: Remove the Exit For from the loop.  I was wondering why you had it there.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictionary` object for handling unique values

here's an example with a late binding Dictionary instance

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim sCharOk As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range, rc As Range
    Dim j As Long

    sCharOk = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-() ~!@#%^&*()_+?'."
    Set r = Range("A1:A10")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instantiate a 'Dictionary' object
        For Each rc In r
            s = rc.Value
            For j = 1 To Len(s)
                If InStr(sCharOk, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then
                    .Item(Mid(s, j, 1)) = .Item(Mid(s, j, 1)) + 1 '<--| stores invalid character in dictionary keys, if not already there
                    rc.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next rc
        Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys) '<--| write down dictionary keys (i.e. unique invalid characters)
    End With
End Sub
```